# Change X-Axis Label in ggtsdisplay() or tsdisplay()Function to Follow Its Series

Tags: r, time-series

I have a montly time series data produced below which I want to check its residual performance but the `x-axis` label on the first plot which is the error plot is awkward.

```
## simulate ARIMA(1,0, 0)
set.seed(1)
ar1 <- arima.sim(n = 12, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
ts <- ts(ar1, start = c(2022, 1), end = c(2022, 12), frequency = 12)
fit_ts<- forecast(auto.arima(ts))
forecast::ggtsdisplay(residuals(fit_ts), plot.type = c("partial", "histogram", "scatter", "spectrum"), theme = theme_bw())
```

[image: I got this plots]

I want the `x-axis` of the first plot to be rebel `2022 Jan, 2022 Mar, 2022 May, 2022 Jul, 2022  Sep, 2022  Nov` and not 2020`

**Edit**

I tried `ggtsdisplay(residuals(fit_bs), plot.type = c("partial", "histogram", "scatter", "spectrum"), theme = theme_bw(), scale_x_discrete(limit = c("2022 Jan", "2022 Feb", "2022 Mar", "2022 Apr", "2022 May", "2022 Jun", "2022 Jul", "2022 Aug", "2022  Sep", "2022 Oct", "2022  Nov", 2022 Dec")))` but it is not working

Comment: have a look at the altered answer - I included a customizable approach, using the ggplot2::scale_x_date() inputs as function inputs date_labels and date_breaks... if you need still more flexibility you can push other arguments to the main function call.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the idea in your comment by adding an edit to your answer?

Comment: the answer has been altered as mentioned - there is a second part just under the first... I included the word "EDIT" now.... observe that the second plot has labels for each third month and uses only the month abreviation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `forecast::ggtsdisplay` function under the hood is building 3 diferent plots and combining them for the output in one plot object. This unfortunately implies/means it is rather complex to alter the final object to get what you need, as it has already been build by multiple function calls.

To work arround this we can see how the function is build calling just the function name and see if we can customize it to your needs:

```
forecast::ggtsdisplay
```

This gets the entire body of the function (luckily nothing OO) and can thus be copied and modified for a custom function definition (modified parts are commented).. the customizing could be done by just calling `zoo::scale_x_yearmon` on the build `ggplot2::autoplot` though it does not behave quite as needed therefore I opted to build the timeline plot from scratch incluiding the setup df:

```
my_ggtsdisplay <- function (x, plot.type = c("partial", "histogram", "scatter", "spectrum"), points = TRUE, smooth = FALSE,  lag.max, na.action = na.contiguous, theme = NULL, ...) 
{
    if (!requireNamespace("ggplot2", quietly = TRUE)) {
        stop("ggplot2 is needed for this function to work. Install it via install.packages(\"ggplot2\")", call. = FALSE)
    }
    else if (!requireNamespace("grid", quietly = TRUE)) {
        stop("grid is needed for this function to work. Install it via install.packages(\"grid\")", call. = FALSE)
    }
    else {
        if (NCOL(x) > 1) {
            stop("ggtsdisplay is only for univariate time series")
        }
        plot.type <- match.arg(plot.type)
        main <- deparse(substitute(x))
        if (!is.ts(x)) {
            x <- ts(x)
        }
        if (missing(lag.max)) {
            lag.max <- round(min(max(10 * log10(length(x)), 3 * frequency(x)), length(x)/3))
        }
        dots <- list(...)
        if (is.null(dots$xlab)) {
            dots$xlab <- ""
        }
        if (is.null(dots$ylab)) {
            dots$ylab <- ""
        }
        labs <- match(c("xlab", "ylab", "main"), names(dots), nomatch = 0)
        gridlayout <- matrix(c(1, 2, 1, 3), nrow = 2)
        grid::grid.newpage()
        grid::pushViewport(grid::viewport(layout = grid::grid.layout(nrow(gridlayout), ncol(gridlayout))))
        matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(gridlayout == 1, arr.ind = TRUE))
        # removed from original function as this is the part beeing subsituted
        # tsplot <<- do.call(ggplot2::autoplot, c(object = quote(x), dots[labs]))
        # convert ts object to data frame to be able to build plot from scratch
        mydf <- data.frame(date = zoo::as.Date.ts(ts),
                           vale = unclass(ts))
        # build the ggplot2 plot incluidng geom_line call (should be equivalent to ggplot2::autoplot from what I understand
        tsplot  <- ggplot2::ggplot(mydf, aes(x = date, y = vale)) + 
            ggplot2::geom_line()

        if (points) {
            tsplot <- tsplot  +
                ggplot2::geom_point(size = .5) + 
                # included the scales call with date abreviation you can use "%Y %b" to show year before month abreviation
                ggplot2::scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y", date_breaks = "1 month")
        }
        if (smooth) {
            tsplot <- tsplot + ggplot2::geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE)
        }
        if (is.null(tsplot$labels$title)) {
            tsplot <- tsplot + ggplot2::ggtitle(main)
        }
        if (!is.null(theme)) {
            tsplot <- tsplot + theme
        }
        print(tsplot, vp = grid::viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row, layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
        acfplot <- do.call(ggAcf, c(x = quote(x), lag.max = lag.max, na.action = na.action, dots[-labs])) + ggplot2::ggtitle(NULL)
        if (!is.null(theme)) {
            acfplot <- acfplot + theme
        }
        if (plot.type == "partial") {
            lastplot <- ggPacf(x, lag.max = lag.max, na.action = na.action) + 
                ggplot2::ggtitle(NULL)
            acfplotrange <- ggplot2::layer_scales(acfplot)$y$range$range
            pacfplotrange <- ggplot2::layer_scales(lastplot)$y$range$range
            yrange <- range(c(acfplotrange, pacfplotrange))
            acfplot <- acfplot + ggplot2::ylim(yrange)
            lastplot <- lastplot + ggplot2::ylim(yrange)
        }
        else if (plot.type == "histogram") {
            lastplot <- gghistogram(x, add.normal = TRUE, add.rug = TRUE) + 
                ggplot2::xlab(main)
        }
        else if (plot.type == "scatter") {
            scatterData <- data.frame(y = x[2:NROW(x)], x = x[1:NROW(x) - 1])
            lastplot <- ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes_(y = ~y,  x = ~x), data = scatterData) + 
                ggplot2::geom_point() + 
                ggplot2::labs(x = expression(Y[t - 1]), y = expression(Y[t]))
        }
        else if (plot.type == "spectrum") {
            specData <- spec.ar(x, plot = FALSE)
            specData <- data.frame(spectrum = specData$spec, frequency = specData$freq)
            lastplot <- ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes_(y = ~spectrum, x = ~frequency), data = specData) + 
                ggplot2::geom_line() + 
                ggplot2::scale_y_log10()
        }
        if (!is.null(theme)) {
            lastplot <- lastplot + theme
        }
        matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(gridlayout == 2, arr.ind = TRUE))
        print(acfplot, vp = grid::viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row, layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
        matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(gridlayout == 3, arr.ind = TRUE))
        print(lastplot, vp = grid::viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row, layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
    }
}

# lets call the customized function just as you would to with the uncustomized
my_ggtsdisplay (residuals(fit_ts), plot.type = c("partial", "histogram", "scatter", "spectrum"), theme = theme_bw())
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

one simple way to make the plot layout adjustable is to take the `date_labels` and `date_breaks` arguments from the `ggplot2::scale_x_date` call as function inputs to your custom function:

```
# include two adicional parameters "dl" and "db"
my_ggtsdisplay <- function (x, plot.type = c("partial", "histogram", "scatter", "spectrum"), points = TRUE, smooth = FALSE,  lag.max, na.action = na.contiguous, theme = NULL, dl = "%Y %b", db = "1 month", ...) 
{
    if (!requireNamespace("ggplot2", quietly = TRUE)) {
        stop("ggplot2 is needed for this function to work. Install it via install.packages(\"ggplot2\")", call. = FALSE)
    }
    else if (!requireNamespace("grid", quietly = TRUE)) {
        stop("grid is needed for this function to work. Install it via install.packages(\"grid\")", call. = FALSE)
    }
    else {
        if (NCOL(x) > 1) {
            stop("ggtsdisplay is only for univariate time series")
        }
        plot.type <- match.arg(plot.type)
        main <- deparse(substitute(x))
        if (!is.ts(x)) {
            x <- ts(x)
        }
        if (missing(lag.max)) {
            lag.max <- round(min(max(10 * log10(length(x)), 3 * frequency(x)), length(x)/3))
        }
        dots <- list(...)
        if (is.null(dots$xlab)) {
            dots$xlab <- ""
        }
        if (is.null(dots$ylab)) {
            dots$ylab <- ""
        }
        labs <- match(c("xlab", "ylab", "main"), names(dots), nomatch = 0)
        gridlayout <- matrix(c(1, 2, 1, 3), nrow = 2)
        grid::grid.newpage()
        grid::pushViewport(grid::viewport(layout = grid::grid.layout(nrow(gridlayout), ncol(gridlayout))))
        matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(gridlayout == 1, arr.ind = TRUE))
        # removed from original function as this is the part beeing subsituted
        # tsplot <<- do.call(ggplot2::autoplot, c(object = quote(x), dots[labs]))
        # convert ts object to data frame to be able to build plot from scratch
        mydf <- data.frame(date = zoo::as.Date.ts(ts),
                           vale = unclass(ts))
        # build the ggplot2 plot incluidng geom_line call (should be equivalent to ggplot2::autoplot from what I understand
        tsplot  <- ggplot2::ggplot(mydf, aes(x = date, y = vale)) + 
            ggplot2::geom_line()

        if (points) {
            tsplot <- tsplot  +
                ggplot2::geom_point(size = .5) + 
                # included the scales fed with function inputs dl and db
                ggplot2::scale_x_date(date_labels = dl, date_breaks = db) +
                # set plot title, in this case empty string
                ggplot2::ggtitle("")
        }
        if (smooth) {
            tsplot <- tsplot + ggplot2::geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE)
        }
        if (is.null(tsplot$labels$title)) {
            tsplot <- tsplot + ggplot2::ggtitle(main)
        }
        if (!is.null(theme)) {
            tsplot <- tsplot + theme
        }
        print(tsplot, vp = grid::viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row, layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
        acfplot <- do.call(ggAcf, c(x = quote(x), lag.max = lag.max, na.action = na.action, dots[-labs])) + ggplot2::ggtitle(NULL)
        if (!is.null(theme)) {
            acfplot <- acfplot + theme
        }
        if (plot.type == "partial") {
            lastplot <- ggPacf(x, lag.max = lag.max, na.action = na.action) + 
                ggplot2::ggtitle(NULL)
            acfplotrange <- ggplot2::layer_scales(acfplot)$y$range$range
            pacfplotrange <- ggplot2::layer_scales(lastplot)$y$range$range
            yrange <- range(c(acfplotrange, pacfplotrange))
            acfplot <- acfplot + ggplot2::ylim(yrange)
            lastplot <- lastplot + ggplot2::ylim(yrange)
        }
        else if (plot.type == "histogram") {
            lastplot <- gghistogram(x, add.normal = TRUE, add.rug = TRUE) + 
                ggplot2::xlab(main)
        }
        else if (plot.type == "scatter") {
            scatterData <- data.frame(y = x[2:NROW(x)], x = x[1:NROW(x) - 1])
            lastplot <- ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes_(y = ~y,  x = ~x), data = scatterData) + 
                ggplot2::geom_point() + 
                ggplot2::labs(x = expression(Y[t - 1]), y = expression(Y[t]))
        }
        else if (plot.type == "spectrum") {
            specData <- spec.ar(x, plot = FALSE)
            specData <- data.frame(spectrum = specData$spec, frequency = specData$freq)
            lastplot <- ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes_(y = ~spectrum, x = ~frequency), data = specData) + 
                ggplot2::geom_line() + 
                ggplot2::scale_y_log10()
        }
        if (!is.null(theme)) {
            lastplot <- lastplot + theme
        }
        matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(gridlayout == 2, arr.ind = TRUE))
        print(acfplot, vp = grid::viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row, layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
        matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(gridlayout == 3, arr.ind = TRUE))
        print(lastplot, vp = grid::viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row, layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
    }
}

# lets call the customized function just as you would to with the uncustomized 
# now we can inform dl and db just as we would date_labels and _breaks
my_ggtsdisplay (residuals(fit_ts), plot.type = c("partial", "histogram", "scatter", "spectrum"), theme = theme_bw(), dl = "%b", db = "3 months")
```

to see which/how inputs can be used for `date_labels` (dl) and `date_breaks` (db), have a look at the [ggplot2::scale_x_date() documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html)

[image]

Comment: Removing the plot title `residuals(fit_ts)` will serve me.

Comment: @DanielJames I have included a ggplot2::ggtitle("") call in the edit which sets an empty title... please run the code again and confirm that it solves your question

Comment: Both functions do not work: Error in attr(x, "tsp") <- c(1, NROW(x), 1) : object is not a matrix. R version 4.3.0